# What scriptable OCR Software exists on OSX for a paperless office

Tags: software-recommendation, script, scanning, ocr

I'm planning to get a paperless office and for that, I a need good scriptable piece of OCR for OS X?

I've read a [blogpost](http://www.marco.org/2011/06/01/mac-pdf-ocr-software) by Marco Arment about a few programs. Are there any workable ones there that allow me to script things?

Comment: Have you ruled out using Image Capture and letting the OS X OCR do it's job? If not, I'd jump to [PDFpen](http://www.smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/) if you think like Marco Arment does in his scriptable [OCR review](http://www.marco.org/2011/06/01/mac-pdf-ocr-software).

Comment: Please review [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/2180/5472) and edit this to describe what precisely you want the software to do and any limitations. Specifically, what scripting language are you looking to leverage?

Comment: There is no OCR built into Image Capture or OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCRKit has both AppleScript support and a CLI. From their [help page](http://ocrkit.com/help/):

> ### AppleScript
>
> You can also script OCRKit to integrate it into your specific workflow.
>   For example process incoming files, via shared folder, from MFP copy
>    machine, etc. and simply tell OCRKit to open and thus process is via
>   AppleScript:
>
> ```
> tell application "OCRKit"
>    -- the wonders of AppleScript POSIX path handling, ...
>    open "Users:admin:Desktop:orderform.pdf"
>    open POSIX path of "/Users/Admin/Desktop/orderform.pdf"
> end tell
> ```
>
> ### **Command line**
>
> Since OCRKit version 2.5 direct command line scripting is supported.
>   This greatly simplifies the use of OCRKit in batch processing, allows
>   to set more options and is also more robust and cross-platform than
>   AppleSCript.
>
> ```
> OCRKit.app/Contents/MacOS/OCRKit \ 
>     --lang en | de | fr | es | ... \
>     --format pdf | html | rtf | text \
>     --no-progress \
>     --output out-file in-file
> ```
>
> Since OCRKit version 16.9 additional command line options are supported:
>
> `-r, --recursive directory`
>
> > Scan directory recursively for new files. Skips files from OCRKit, with text layer or vector graphics.
>
> `--pattern "regex"`
>
> > Pattern used to match filenames during recursive scans. Defaults to `%.pdf$`, recommendation for TIFF is `%.tiff?$`
>
> `--log file`
>
> > Write log file information and statistics during recursive scan to file.
>
> `--password secret`
>
> > Use secret password to decrypt PDF files during batch processing.
>
> `--test-run [ fast ]`
>
> > Only run test batch processing in test mode to test PDF files or to
> >     obtain page count to estimate total processing time. "fast" will only 
> >     check the first page of each file, instead of going thru all pages for 
> >     image and vector analyzation.
>
> `--tag name`
>
> > Use extended attribute name to tag the processing state of files
> >     during batch processing. `macos:OCRKit (%s)` will use native macOS
> >     Finder tags instead, or simply `macos:OCRKit` not including the state 
> >     attribute. The order of the state attribute are: `started`, `analyzed`, 
> >     `processed`, and can also be `encrypted`.

Answer (score 1):

[Readiris for Mac.](http://www.irislink.com/c2-1685-189/Readiris-12-for-Mac.aspx) I have it, but I haven't used it in a long time, so I don't exactly remember how good it was. I think that it didn't do the first few documents very well, but it learns.

<strike>Oh, and I'm not sure about scriptability. I'll check it.</strike>

It looks like Readiris has a scripting dictionary, and it's pretty good, too.

Answer (score 0):

ABBYY FineReader Pro for Mac does OCR well and is scriptable. From their [blurb page](https://www.abbyy.com/en-ca/finereader/pro-for-mac/features/):

> Process Batches of Documents and Automate Conversion Tasks
>
> Achieve new levels of productivity and enjoy greater flexibility when converting documents with support for Automator actions and AppleScript commands.

It supports both Applescript and Automator. I hadn't tried to automate it previously but after looking into it, I have some plans to do some basic stuff. This is really why I'm belatedly 'answering' this question.