# Automator-script with an OCR-software to automatically add OCR to material?

Tags: macos, automator, adobe, ocr, scanning

*The OCR software could be anything like PDFPen, ABBYY FineReader Express or Adobe Acrobat Pro. Automator does not list any features such as 'Add OCR layer to' or show any OCR programs under Automator.*

I try to make a high-level script to automate addition of OCR layer to different kind of material such as images, PDFs and screenshots. I am trying to solve a puzzle related to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76471/make-existing-pdf-searchable-ocr-via-command-line-script). For example, how can I add OCR to books in my iTunes without OCR? This would be extremely needed feature because it would make reading of material over iPhone, iPad and OS X much more conformtable. Also, the addition of OCR would improve search results in Finder. So:

> **How can I do an automator script with an OCR program such as the ABBYY to automatically add OCR to material that does not have the OCR layer?**

Comment: At least at first glance this question looks extremely similar to the one you link to? To avoid having it closed as a duplicate, how would you describe the difference?

Comment: @patrix this is a specific and answerable question -- the other question is not specific and not answerable. I would suggest closing the other question and not this one because it is very hard to understand what the other op tries to ask. There is nothing similar with the questions: this is specifially about OCR and Automator in OS X while the other is about -- I don't know, I want to get clean specific threads without excess clutter.

Comment: The goal is to have questions which are specific enough to be helpful and broad enough to be answerable. So if I have the choice between "scriptable OCR solution" and "Automator-scriptable OCR solution" the first one is preferable (and has already been answered). Let's close this one as a duplicate, feel free to take the discussion to Meta if you don't agree.

Comment: @patrix your writing makes no sense but you are mod: do whatever you want, it is not the first time I cannot understand moderators on this site. I even doubt whether moderator understand actions of one another. Simplicity first, this is far easier to answer than the other question. If you cannot answer, do not think other people could not.