# Easiest/cheapest way to OCR an existing PDF that lacks a text layer?

Tags: software-recommendation, preview, ocr

I have photo-scanned one of my most-used reference works, [Watching the Skies](https://www.abebooks.co.uk/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30229332030&searchurl=an%3Djack%2Bgough%26n%3D100121503%26sortby%3D17%26tn%3Dwatching%2Bskies%2Bhistory%2Bground&cm_sp=snippet-_-srp1-_-title1). The aim was to allow me to do searches instead of using the (somewhat odd) index. I copied the images off my iphone and used Preview on my mac to produce a single PDF with all of the pages. The result is surprisingly good.

So now I have a huge document of fairly readable scanned images. But there is no "text layer" that I can search. Is there a way to do that within Preview, or some other tool I can use?

Comment: Today I learned that even though Preview OCRs images and allows you to copy text out of an image it will not let you search for text in an image. I also learned that it does not OCR images in PDF files at all. I thought Preview would do both of those things and now I am wondering why it does not.

Comment: Can you post a page (one with lots of text) from the book and I can run OwlOCR and Nitro PDF with it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76471/make-existing-pdf-searchable-ocr-via-command-line-script?rq=1. But that question and its answers are old enough that it is IMO worth addressing again.

Comment: @DaveNelson - this is a mystery to me, especially after they added LiveText, which does precisely this, but only manually, and only on a selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use [Tesseract](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/)

This is open source OCR software available on [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/tesseract/) or [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tesseract) that can output to several formats:

- txt
- pdf
- hocr
- tsv
- pdf with text layer only

Ideally, you’d want to take the image first (before making a PDF) and let Tesseract create the searchable PDF for you:

```
tesseract foobar.tif foobar pdf
```

However, if you already have an existing PDF, they have this solved for you as indicated in the [FAQs](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ.html#how-do-i-integrate-original-image-file-and-detected-text-into-pdf)

> Use the config variable `-c textonly_pdf=1` and Merge your image-only and text-only PDF.
>
> See https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/660#issuecomment-274213632 for details.

Comment: I'd use [pdfsandwich](http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich) which uses tesseract under the hood, but also uses other tools to do straightening of scans, and etc.

Comment: I have used @MarcWilson suggestion and used pdfsandwich, which did a fantastic job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Use [OwlOCR](https://owlocr.com)**

This is a modestly priced OCR product (from the Apple App Store), which in my experience performs just as well as more expensive products like PDFPen Pro (now Nitro PDF Pro).

Whenever I have tried free OCR (most notably Tesseract), I have been thoroughly disappointed in the results.

Opinion: OCR on the Mac has been revolutionised by the inbuilt Image to Text engine. Quality OCR is no longer restricted to expensive products. My understanding is that OwlOCR (and a few others) tap into this engine.