# Search over different types of documents such as DjVU sometimes without OCR?

Tags: macos, ios, search, ocr

Suppose Apple products such as iOS devices and OS X devices at hand. You want to make things searchable. Some files such as converted PDFs lack OCR so you cannot search them. Some formats are not supported by OCR tools. Root [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68849/ipad-app-to-search-all-content-in-pdf-files/70038#70038) broken:

> 1. How to search over different types of documents such as DjVU?
> 2. Online tools? OS X tools? iOS tools? What about files without OCR?

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is bad, again -- poor people.

Comment: It's impossible to search an image without some kind of OCR, so the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. How to search over different types of documents such as DjVU?**

> I would convert them first into PDF and then use some well-known OCR-tool such as Adobe Acrobat PRO. You can get it with the Creative Suite to make documents searchable. In order to convert certain type into PDF, I would use Online Converters such as the DjVU Online Converter such as [here](http://www.docspal.com/). The OCR requires a lot of computation power so probably best done with Desktop tools unless cloud-tool or iOS tool found.

**II. Online tools? OS X tools? iOS tools? What about files without OCR?**

> Docspal.com for converting. Desktop tools such as Adobe Acrobat PRO (in Creative Suite) for adding the OCR. PDFPen OS X should also work with the OCR and they have the iOS version as well.

**Further information**

> 1. [Looking for Software to Scan or Convert to Searchable and Signable PDF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72676/looking-for-software-to-scan-or-convert-to-searchable-and-signable-pdf)
> 2. [Make existing PDF searchable ( OCR ) via command line / script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76471/make-existing-pdf-searchable-ocr-via-command-line-script) and [What scriptable OCR Software exists on OSX for a paperless office](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24512/best-scriptable-ocr-software-for-osx-for-a-paperless-office)